# how to exclude an anchor from "e.stopPropagation()"

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-lists, stoppropagation

```
$pageslide.click(function(e) {
e.stopPropagation();
});
```

That prevents the #pageslide ID or Class from sliding if clicked, how do i exclude certain elements from being prevented, in this case i want to exclude `<a></a>` or `<li></li>`. Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.target` property of the event object refers to the target of the event, you can read this property:

```
$pageslide.click(function(e) {
   if ( $.inArray(e.target.localName, ['li', 'a']) < 0 ) {
      e.stopPropagation();
   }
});
```

Or use `.closest()` method:

```
if ( $(e.target).closest('a').length === 0 ) {
   e.stopPropagation();
}
```

Comment: So adding 'a' to be excluded makes every 'a' to trigger that slide, how do I add some ID of a not to trigger slide.?

Answer (score 2):

Use jQuery's filter method.

```
$pageslide.filter('a li').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```